# How many devices can run behind a Network Address Translation (NAT) device?

Tags: networking, port, ip-address, nat, internet-connection

I was studying about Network Address Translation devices in a networking course (CS144, Stanford).

They described that a NAT works by mapping local IP address and corresponding application port numbers to the NAT's external IP and assigned (by the NAT) port number for that connection.

Assume that there is only one single external IP address to the NAT. My question is as follows:

Since the bottleneck to the number of connections between the internet and the NAT here is the limit on port numbers (which can go upto 65535), does that limit the number of applications (running on various devices behind the NAT) which can access the Internet, and also the number of devices that can run behind the NAT?

If yes, how can this limit be increased so that there can be unlimited devices behind the NAT?

Comment: I wanted to clarify that I watched youtube videos of the course and read their notes and am not enrolled in the course. This question is also not related to any assignments/homework in the course. Mentioning this because someone downvoted this question and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a good question.

As you said, NAT is limited by the port numbers. But the thing is that the protocol use a tuple like : internal IP, internal Port, external IP, external Port, and protocol.

So, if we only have one external IP, then port numbers (65536) and protocol (TCP/UDP) will be the limitation. Since we can only map to 65546 * 2 external Port and protocol, that is the limitation of internal connection.

If you want to break the limitation, maybe it's best to increase the number of external IP addresses.

Comment: One internal device could theoretically connect, using only TCP and a single port number to every IPv4 address and TCP port number combination outside the NAPT because the return traffic from all the outside devices, while using the single address and port number as the destination, will also have a different source address and port number, so you can multiply that by 65,535 (port 0 cannot be used) for s single inside device. The NAPT device will not have enough RAM for a table that large.

Answer (score 1):

I found some clarity on this question. The limit of 65535 is per public ip per remote host.

https://serverfault.com/questions/541699/nat-gateway-maximum-connection-limit

Comment: That is not actually correct. You mean NAPT which is the variant of NAT that allows hiding multiple devices behind a single IPv4 address. There will be three NAPT tables, one for each of TCP (uses ports), UDP (uses the same port numbers as TCP, but TCP and UDP ports are not the same), and ICMP (uses Query IDs). Each table will use both the source and destination IPv4 and transport addresses (ports/IDs), so you can theoretically have millions of processes per device behind the NAT, but the NAT memory will limit it to far less.

Comment: Put another way, the index per each of the three NAPT table is 32 bits for the source IPv4 address plus 16 bits for the source transport protocol address plus 32 bits for the destination IPv4 address plus 16 bits for the destination transport protocol address. That means that the theoretical maximum table size is 2^96 (79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336) entries per protocol, so multiply by three for all three protocols. That is unrealistic, so the RAM on the NAPT device is the limit on translations.

Comment: @Ron Maupin is it correct to say the following? If 70000 devices behind the NAT wanted to connect to the same remote host application (which has a single ip address) using tcp, then since the table can only route responses from the host using the destination port number now (same source ip, same source port, same destination ip, same protocol: tcp), then there would be a problem? Essentially would 70000 devices be able to connect to a single small application simultaneously using the same protocol?